# check for name in class and then print out the result

Tags: python, oop

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

p1 = Person("John", 36)

print(p1.name)
print(p1.age)

name = input("inter name ")

for i in p1:
    if name in i.name:
        print(true)
```

I want the program to check if name in in the class Person and if it there is print true

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `for i in p1:`, what do you think this should mean, and why? What do you think should be the value of `i` each time through the loop?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `for` for checking a single item property. Yous should just,

```
p1 = Person("John", 36)
person_name = input("inter name ")

if p1.name == person_name:
    print(True)  # Boolean True is capitalized.  "true" is undefined.
else:
    #sth else
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a while loop, if you would try it again:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    def get_age(self):
        return self.age


def main():
    p1 = Person("John", 36)
    while input !=  'quit':
        name = input("Enter name or 'quit': ")
         
        if name == p1.get_name():
            print(f"{p1.get_name()} was the right name!")
            print(f"and {p1.get_name()} is {p1.get_age()} years old.")
            break
        if name == "quit":
            break
        else:
            print(f"{name} was the wrong naem, try another name again.")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```